# Server Clustering?

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

Good afternoon all. I am not sure this is possible but thought I would ask.

I have 2 identical vhosts running Ubuntu 16. Both of those hosts are image download servers. I have roughly 20million images that are being downloaded starting from 1998 to the current year.

My question is this:

Is it possible to request an image file, and have it served from the appropriate server. I don't want both servers downloading the same images. Lets say server 1 is downloading from 2009 to current year, server 2 has 1998 to 2008.

I am already using a proxy server to route requests to the 2 servers, but they are just being routed to images1.domain.com and images2.domain.com.

It would be nice if I could direct my website image requests to images.domain.com and the server containing the actual file respond to the request.

Hopefully I didn't completely botch the asking of this question.

Comment: Do the download paths have some way to identify the year? I mean, if you have `/1991/foo/bar/img1.png` and `/2006/nofoo/nobar/img.png`, you could have the proxy server send requests for the first one way and the second the other way. Then one server could keep images from 1998-2008 and the other from 2009-now.

Comment: There is no year data in the image name. They are named by a unique id asdociated with a property listing

Comment: Then split based on characters in the ID or something. Say id begins with a-o, one server, and p-9, other server.

Comment: In short: no, you cannot do what you suggest. The common way to solve this would either be to have one backend server, and two caching front ends, or simply round robin dns between the two servers, and both having all the content, possibly shared via NFS from a common storage server. Alternatively, in the code that hands out the link, code it such that it gets directed appropriately.